# Test difference in survey response rates

Tags: hypothesis-testing

My company sends out employee satisfaction surveys, and attaches bonuses to some of them, so I'm trying to test if giving bonuses increases a survey's response rate. The response rate without bonuses is .377 (22k sample size), .395 with bonuses (11k sample size).

Is there a particular type of test that would be suited for comparing these statistics and seeing if the difference in response rate is statistically significant?

Answer (score 1):

**Test of equal proportions.** The procedure `prop.test` in R should do what
you want. You need to use counts. So the number
of responses Without Bonuses is $.377(22\,000) \approx 6094$ and With is $.395(11\,000)\approx 4345.$ (Please proofread my transcription.)

Then the test is as shown below. The P-value very near $0$ indicates a difference in proportions
that is highly statistically significant. [In effect, this test uses a normal approximation for
the P-value, but with such large samples the
approximation should be quite good, and the optional continuity correction can be declined
(with parameter `cor=F`).]

```
prop.test(c(6094,4345), c(22000,11000), cor=F)

        2-sample test for 
        equality of proportions 
        without continuity correction

data:  c(6094, 4345) out of c(22000, 11000)
X-squared = 472.15, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.1288823 -0.1071177
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
 0.277  0.395
```

**Chi-squared test of homogeneity.** The test above is essentially the same as a chi-squared test (without a Yates correction) on the
$2\times 2$ table of counts with rows "With" and "Without"
and columns "Responded" and "No Response" and grand total $33\,000.$ The P-value
of the chi-squared test is the same as for `prop.test`.

```
r = c(6094, 4345);  n = c(22000,11000)
nr = n - r
TBL = cbind(r,nr);  TBL
        r    nr
[1,] 6094 15906
[2,] 4345  6655

chisq.test(TBL, cor=F)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 472.15, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

If you are familiar with chi-squared tests, you may be interested to see
tables of expected counts (under the null
hypothesis that proportions are homogeneous) and of Pearson residuals, as
shown below:

```
chisq.test(TBL, cor=F)$exp
            r        nr
[1,] 6959.333 15040.667
[2,] 3479.667  7520.333

chisq.test(TBL, cor=F)$resi
             r        nr
[1,] -10.37289  7.055859
[2,]  14.66948 -9.978491
```

The chi-squared test statistic $472.15$
is the sum of squares of the four Pearson
residuals.